# Exposing multiple ports using Kestrel and IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

We are building services on the .NET Core stack. Currently we are hosting these using Kestrel behind the IIS reverse proxy.

These services have some business functionality, and some admin/config functionality. One idea we are playing with is to expose these on different ports.

Is it possible to expose multiple ports using Kestrel and IIS today? This scenario should be possible using Docker and Kubernetes, but we are not there yet.